# Express app cannot find index.html

Tags: node.js, express, tessel

I'm having a problem with my Express app when I push it to my Tessel 2, I'm able to get this working locally but once it's pushed onto another system it causes problems. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tmp/remote-script/public/index.html'
    at Error (native)
```

And this is my Express route setup:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
})
```

I've tried several different file path locations such as `/../public/index.html` and none of them seem to work. My directory structure has `index.js` as the primary node file, and then I have a public directory with the `index.html` file within it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `res.sendFile('./public/index.html');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the Tessel 2 not Node, I needed to update the `.tesselinclude` file to push the public directory to the device, like so: `public/**`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use absolute paths in `express.static`

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Then

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
```

Also i would suggest instead of the above you should use `render`

```
res.render('index')
```

Comment: I still end up with the same error with the above code, however using `res.render('index')` results in an error saying `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

Comment: if its still coming with res.render also then try `/static/index.html`

Comment: Same deal, if I use `res.render('index.html')` instead it says `Error: Cannot find module 'html'`

Comment: try only `res.render('index')`

Comment: I did, see my first comment. Might have edited it as you replied the first time.

Comment: really sorry i misunderstood something. You have to configure a view engine like jade or pug. Also sendFile with an html won't work as expected it will just download the file so res.render will be the only option. Also with jade or pug you have to rename your file to `.jade` or `.pug`

Comment: really sorry i misunderstood something. You have to configure a view engine like jade or pug. Also sendFile with an html won't work as expected it will just download the file so res.render will be the only option. Also with jade or pug you have to rename your file to `.jade` or `.pug`

Comment: We might benefit more from knowing reasoning behind where the file is located relative to the project and if it can be moved to a more suitable location.

Comment: Personally, I would install EJS so you can benefit from embedding JS. https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: Ejs handlebars pug all of them are good. You can use anyone you want.